# Inner join in sqlite and python takes longer time to execute

Tags: python, sqlite, join

I have 2 tables named geostat and res. I want to do an inner join on those two tables and store the result in to tables. I know the sql queryu for the same but when I do it in python using sqlite, It seems to take longer time to execute the query (approx 1hr which is not good). I wonder since it has an inner join does it take longer time to execute? How do I optimize the query?

My sql query is :

```
select res.[MaxOfState count percent], res.[grpno.], geostat.[state code] from res inner join geostat on res.[MaxOfState count percent] = geostat.[count percent] AND res.[grpno.] = geostat.[grpno.]
```

My tables are as follows:

```
geostat:
   count percent  grpno. state code
0          14.78       1         CA
1           0.00       2         CA
2           8.80       3         CA
3           9.60       4         FL
4          55.90       4         MA
5           0.00       2         FL
6           0.00       6         NC
7           0.00       5         NC
8           6.90       1         FL
9          59.00       4         MA
res:
   grpno.  MaxOfcount percent
0       1               14.78
1       2                0.00
2       3                8.80
3       4               59.00
4       5                0.00
5       6                0.00
```

Now when i execute the inner join query it takes more than an hour to execute. My code in python is as below:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # database connection
disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///fnma.db') # Initializes database with filename fnma.db in current directory
inner_join_geostat = pd.read_sql('select res.[MaxOfState count percent], res.[grpno.], geostat.[state code] from res inner join geostat on res.[MaxOfState count percent] = geostat.[count percent] AND res.[grpno.] = geostat.[grpno.]  ',disk_engine)
inner_join_geostat.to_sql('inner_join_geostat', disk_engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Can anyone tell me how to optimise the query/code?

My explain query plan is as follows:

```
selectid    order   from    detail
0           0       0       SCAN TABLE geostat_query_recent
0           1       1       SEARCH TABLE geostatdf_recent1 USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (STATE POOL NUMBER=? AND STATE COUNT PERCENT=?)
```

FYI: I haven't created an index yet.

Comment: Do you have the right indexes? Did you try a DB server instead of SQLite?

Comment: I did not create an index for the tables. Also I just started up with the SQLite initially.

Comment: Then create indexes on the fields you are joining. It will speed it up significantly. Might be helpful: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexes.htm

Comment: Thank you :) I will try it right a way.

Comment: Old Python versions use old SQLite versions. Anyway, show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for this query.

Comment: can anyone please help me on this?